# WebRTC video stream error - scaledrone

Tags: webrtc

Does anyone know what has changed with WebRTC in the past month or two?
I had a WebRTC video web app that was running just fine around two months ago and now randomly stopped working. I used scaledrone for the singling

This is the tutorial I followed:
[https://www.scaledrone.com/blog/posts/webrtc-tutorial-simple-video-chat](https://scaledrone.github.io/webrtc/index.html)

The only Error I get is this which doesen't say anything to me:

```
DOMException: Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable
```

Demo can be seen here:
[enter link description here](https://scaledrone.github.io/webrtc/index.html)

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ah their GitHub is actually updated. Will try to remove the question

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/Qxj38DwiJPU/5eCOPWvwBgAJ -- chrome 66 is checking the signaling state more strictly which might break code that isn't doing the right thing

Answer (score 2):

It is the RTCPeerConnection.signalingState. The possible values are:

- **stable** − The initial state. There is no SDP offer/answer exchange in progress
- have-local-offer − the local side of the connection has locally
  applied a SDP offer
- have-remote-offer − the remote side of the connection has locally
  applied a SDP offer
- have-local-pranswer − a remote SDP offer has been applied, and a SDP
  pranswer applied locally
- have-remote-pranswer − a local SDP has been applied, and a SDP
  pranswer applied remotely
- closed − the connection is closed

You see the WebRTC negotiaton process in the picture that I added down below. 
[image]

**DOMException: Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable** means that "your Browser" does not get any SDP offer/answer, which you see in the picture above. That can depend on Browser incompatibility to the scaledrone WebRTC-Wrapper implementation or for example certain STUN problems, which refer to Scaledron implementation too.

Very often it is reported, that for the first use of a "new" channel-id it works only one time and after that never again for the requesting identity.

We suppose that in the ***identity assertion request process*** there is a "count" (operations queue) for authenticated identities (*target peer identity value*) which is extremely unstable - see - https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcconfiguration-peeridentity .

```
function startWebRTC(isOfferer) 
{
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    var identity = pc.peerIdentity;
    ...
    ...
    if (identity) 
    {
          alert("Identity of the peer: idp='" 
                 + identity.idp + "'; assertion='" 
                 + identity.name + "'");
    }
    else 
    {
          alert("Identity of the peer has not been verified");
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Where "configuration" is:

```
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{
    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};
```

[image: Debugger]

https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/  4.4.1.2 Enqueue an operation:
"... an RTCPeerConnection object has an operations queue, [[Operations]], which ensures that only one asynchronous operation in the queue is executed concurrently. If subsequent calls are made while the returned promise of a previous call is still not settled, they are added to the queue and executed when all the previous calls have finished executing and their promises have settled ..." ... see the next steps ...

But to evaluate that is extremly difficult without direct analysing tools. The scaledrone wrapper implementation of ***WebRTC is extremely sensitive***.

We would have to check RTCPeerConnection.iceConnectionState, RTCPeerConnection.peerIdentity, RTCPeerConnection.localDescription, RTCPeerConnection.remoteDescription, RTCPeerConnection.signalingState, ... .

I made some comparing tests with nodejs websockets with Firefox-Quantum-65.0 x64 and Chrome-71.0, which you can see here:
[image: Firefox]
[image]

You see that there is a big difference in it.
Best
Axel